# The moment generating function of two poisson distributed random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

It is equal to:
$E[e^\lambda(x_1 + x_2)]$
Which is equal to:
$E[e^\lambda(x_1] * E[e^\lambda(x_2)]$
which is equal to the moment generating function of $x_2  $ and $  x_1 $
which is equal to:

$e^{\lambda_1 et -\lambda_1}$ $e^{\lambda_2 et -\lambda_2}$

I don't understand the last step. Shouldn't it be $\int p(x) * e^{tx} $ where p(x) is the poisson pmf, which is equal to $(e^-\lambda * \lambda) / x!$ ?

Comment: Is $e^{\lambda_1 et -\lambda_1}$ the moment generating function of a poisson distributed random variable and was obtained using $\int p(x) * e^{tx}$? If it's the case, how did we get to that number? we can't integrate x! right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poissson is a **discrete** distribution. If $X$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, then $\Pr(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. Thus
$$E(e^{tX})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{kt}.$$
Rewrite the above as 
$$e^{-\lambda}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ (\lambda e^t)^k}{k!}                       \right).$$
We recognize the sum,  since in general $\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$.

So our mgf is $e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda e^t}$. If we bring the $e^{-\lambda}$ "inside" we get the more compact formss
$$e^{\lambda e^t-\lambda}, \quad \text{or} \quad e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}.$$

Comment: Can you explain to me what this is and where it comes from: $e^{\lambda_1 et -\lambda_1}$? It is supposed to be the moment generating function of $X_!$, which is a poisson distributed random variable.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry about the typos, I was cutting and pasting so one typo became three.